# NextGen-Gallery show gallery but display only one image to click on

Tags: wordpress, nextgen-gallery

To keep it short: I am working on a Wordpress website for a cliënt of mine and I want to display a gallery with the NextGen Gallery plugin.

What I want to achieve is the following: I want to display one image, and when someones clicks on that image it will open up the gallery in lightbox.

The exact same effect which I want to recreate can be find here: http://www.nextgen-gallery.com/imagebrowser/

But for some reason the Imagebrowser setting in the plugin only contains the navigation arrows underneath the image and not the lightbox effect.

The website on which I am working now can be find at: http://makramedia.beta-projects.nl/fotos/.
Also the lightbox effect is different here then on the website of NextGen Gallery and it only shows the first image of the gallery as if it was the only picture added. I have checked this in the admin but all images are added but not shown on the website.

(To make the website more clear, my client wants that every image on that webpage has its own gallery. I now have 3 images which should open 3 galleries but these don't work properly. )

I really hope someone can help me with this as I have already spent days on getting this fixed. If you need any additional info or data then please don't hessitate to ask me as I'm more than happy if someone can help me with this issue.

Your's sincerely,

Christiaan Bruinsma
Freelance Media Designer

Comment: have you solved this? I've run across the same issue